# Add forms dynamic with Angular 6 using FormGroup

Tags: angular, angular6, form-control, formgroups

I'm trying to make a dynamic form using FormGroup, FormArray etc with Angular 6..
I have a problem when I add a new form and when I enter a value in one input it is reflected in the other inputs of my form.

you can see it here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-4crhvw

How can I solve it so that the data does not duplicate itself in other inputs?

Thxx

Comment: You have only one `Adresse` object and all of the form controls are bound to the properties on that one object - hence them sharing values. If you want a form with multiple `Adresse` objects you need an array of objects and to bind the value of each set of inputs to a specific object in that array.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the fix. Please use this updated code.

```
<form [formGroup]='addressForm' style="margin-top:30px">
    <div formArrayName='adresseRows'>
        <div *ngFor="let formGroup of adresseList().controls;let i=index;">
            <div [formGroupName]="i">
                Label :<input type="name" name="label" formControlName="label" >
        Rue :<input type="name" name="rue" formControlName="rue" > 
        Nom :<input type="name" name="nomRue" formControlName="nomRue">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" (click)="add();">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>Add</button>
    <button type="button" [disabled]="addressForm.invalid" class="btn valid-button" (click)="finish();">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok" aria-hidden="true"></span> Terminer </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Exactly thanks this is a solution..

But I will have a problem loading the address list for example

if I have an address list: 
`listAddres = [ {label:'labs1', street :'2', nameRue:'allerte'}, {label:'Olabel', street :'3', nameRue:'allerte'}];` how could I load it into my html to fill in the forms? I updated it

Comment: While creating a form control, you can pass first paramater as value if exist or else null.    createForms(): FormGroup {
    return new FormGroup({
      label: new FormControl((value) ?value : '' , []),
      rue: new FormControl((value) ?value : '', []),
      nomRue: new FormControl((value) ?value : '', [])
    }, { validators: addresseValidator });
  }

Comment: Ook, but what is 'value' ?? I tried it in stackblitz but does not work